# Sentimental analysis- selection of the most appropriate software

Tags: text-mining, sentiment-analysis

Need some info on machine learning, especially sentiment analysis. I need a software that can parse through a comment(collected from social media platforms) and then judge its polarity(positiveness vs negativeness) on multiple attributes.

Say - the attributes are cleanliness, service-promptness, ease of room booking
And the comment is - 
" was able to book a room easily. However rooms werent very clean"
Then the result would be - 1. Cleanliness- negative 2. ease of booking - positive 3. promptness- neutral

Any leads on what software I can go for or if there are any pre-written programs on this in a language that is easily available online.

Answer (score 0):

I'm researching the same area as you, from what i found out, SVM Classifier gives the best result regarding sentiment-analysis